# Non converging Example for Regula falsi

Tags: roots, weak-convergence, bisection, regula-falsi

I am writing a paper on different methods to calculate roots. One method that I am explaining is Regula falsi. I am also comparing it to bisection and found out that Regula Falsi apparently does not always converge and that, for certain Intervalls, it does not work. And because I didn't find any examples for this problem I wanted to ask, if anyone can give me one.

Excuse my bad english
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is regula falsi?

Comment: @moo i read it on the german wikipedia page on bisection where it says:  "Bisection is suitable for the following cases: The initial values of the classical methods (Newton's method, Regula falsi) are not sufficiently close to the root, so that no local convergence occurs there"

Comment: @cineel https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regula_falsi

Comment: What do you mean Regula Falsi does not always converge? The whole point of it compared to the secant method is that it always converges, provided you give it a bracket like with bisection.